# How to add custom syntax high lighting in IntelliJ (batari Basic)

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, basic, batari-basic

[batari Basic](https://github.com/batari-Basic/batari-Basic) is the programming language for writing games for the Atari 2600 console. The compiled code can be played via an emulator like '[Stella](https://stella-emu.github.io/)'.

I'm still learning batari, but would like to use IntelliJ if possible for the syntax high-lighting and auto-complete features. Is there a way to teach IntelliJ 15 how to do that for a new language by referencing some src code or setting IDE language parameters? The most promising lead I have is this blogpost from 2010. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: The answer is to write your own plugin that supports the language, and can offer context enough into the language to offer that kind of behavior.  Consequently, that's *entirely* too broad for this site; getting started on "how to write an IntelliJ plugin" specifically for that language would be incredibly broad.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't know if such a plugin existed already or not, though I could probably have guessed based on overall amount of information I'm finding on developing this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Adding to @Makoto's suggestion, here's a slightly more updated link to a [custom language support tutorial](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support_tutorial.html) in IntelliJ platform SDK.

Comment: Change to Visual Studio Code and install Atari Dev Studio  :)  
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chunkypixel.atari-dev-studio